# Backup SQL Server database on local PC

Tags: sql-server

I am using this script to backup my SQL Server database on computer A:

```
sqlcmd -U MyDatabase -P MyPassword -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation = 'c:\shared', @databaseName='MyDatabase', @BackupType='F'"
```

Everything works fine, but I decided to store backup files to computer B. I shared folder on computer B, which is accessible from:

```
\\computerB\shared
```

I changed backup script to include new backup location:

```
sqlcmd -U MyDatabase -P MyPassword -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation = '\\computerB\shared', @databaseName='MyDatabase', @BackupType='F'"
```

But when I run this, I get this error:

> Cannot open backup device '\computerB\shared\MyDatabase_FULL_101 22022_232734.BAK'. Operating system error 5 (Access denied
> .).
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-C28934ASNF1\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I don't understand why am I getting `Access denied`. I can easily access `\\computerB\shared` from file explorer on computer A. What is wrong here?

Comment: Probably the service account SQL Server is running under doesn't have permission to access that folder - the default account (rightly) has very limited permissions.

Comment: ^Bingo. Verify the Windows folder permissions for the account your SQL Server instance's service is running under.

Answer (score 3):

We have to think carefully about the user account running the backup process.

When you access the `\\computerB\shared` location in Windows File Explorer, you use your own user account. When you run the `sqlcmd` script it's probably also with your own user account. However, the script is telling SQL Server to perform the backup action; it does not perform the backup directly on it's own. SQL Server is running using a *different account*. This different account does not have access to the shared folder.

To fix this, you can change the account used to run SQL Server, or you can let SQL Server backup locally and then copy or more the files to the share after the backup completes.

What you will probably NOT be able to do is grant SQL Server's current service account access to the shared folder, because it is most likely a special account like SYSTEM (hopefully not) or Network Service that can't be given this access.